# Xero API Access request Auth 2.0 doesn't work

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to use AUth 2.0 but the following request doesn't work. I'm following the instructions from here https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/sign-in

The request throws 500 error no error details. Can someone spot any issues with this redirect url?

https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=F26E013795684C95B584B1E4B70AAB0A&redirect_uri=https://www.mspmate.com&scope=openid profile email

client id is correct and the redirect_uri is the same in the App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a client secret for your client before the client can be used.

Cheers,
Matt